# Are there any Latin language certifications in Europe?

Tags: untagged

I would like to give myself a goal in my learning of the Latin language, as is the case with AP (if I remember correctly) in the United States.
I live in England at the moment but I travel quite often to France, Italy, Germany, etc.
Is there an exam I could take?

I found [Latin Cert](https://www.latin-cert.org) but I don't know if it's legit.

This question is related to (but broader than) that one: [French certification for Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/14303/french-certification-for-latin)

Answer (score 5):

In England where you live, in the relatively few schools that still teach Latin, pupils can sit Latin GCSE (typically at age 16) or the more advanced Latin AS Level or Latin A Level (typically at age 18).

You can sit these exams at any age (see https://www.gcseonlinecourses.co.uk/post/adults-gcse ) and don't need to be taking a course in order to do so.

Another UK option is a Diploma in Classical Studies with the Open University ( https://www.open.ac.uk/courses/arts/diplomas/diploma-in-classical-studies-w62 ), but you would then take their course rather than simply the exams, and the prices are quite high now.

Answer (score 3):

The [International Baccalaurate Diploma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IB_Diploma_Programme), a qualification usually completed around age 18 by high school/equivalent students, offers [Latin](https://www.ibo.org/programmes/diploma-programme/curriculum/language-acquisition/classical-languages/) as a language acquisition option, which can be taken at either Higher Level or Standard Level. The course would typically be taken as one of six subjects to gain the overall diploma, but it would be possible to take Latin by itself for a certificate. It is taught around the world, although predominantly at international schools.